# How to find faulty memory module from MCE message?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I am trying to understand MCE message to find which memory module is bad on a server. This message appears in `/var/log/kern.log` in one server that freezes two times today.

```
Apr 13 22:39:22 mbox kernel: [36247975.116860] sbridge: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
Apr 13 22:39:22 mbox kernel: [36247975.116867] CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 0 Bank 5: 8c00004000010090
Apr 13 22:39:22 mbox kernel: [36247975.116869] TSC 0 ADDR 4a0d75900 MISC 21405cdc86 PROCESSOR 0:206d7 TIME 1428957562 SOCKET 0 APIC 0
Apr 13 22:39:22 mbox kernel: [36247975.951013] EDAC MC0: 1 CE memory read error
```

I suspect a bad memory module. The server is a 2x Xeon E5-2650 with 8x8Go memory modules (8 memory slots for each cpu)

Here is the memory module population from `lshw`:

```
 *-memory:0
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 2d
      slot: System board or motherboard
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-197.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 0
         serial: B83AE5C2
         slot: P1_DIMMA1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm1_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm1_Manufacturer
         physical id: 1
         serial: Dimm1_SerNum
         slot: P1_DIMMA2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 2
         serial: EC309238
         slot: P1_DIMMB1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm4_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm4_Manufacturer
         physical id: 3
         serial: Dimm4_SerNum
         slot: P1_DIMMB2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:4
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 4
         serial: E9305438
         slot: P1_DIMMC1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:5
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm7_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm7_Manufacturer
         physical id: 5
         serial: Dimm7_SerNum
         slot: P1_DIMMC2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:6
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 6
         serial: E7305738
         slot: P1_DIMMD1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:7
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm10_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm10_Manufacturer
         physical id: 7
         serial: Dimm10_SerNum
         slot: P1_DIMMD2
         width: 64 bits
 *-memory:1
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 3f
      slot: System board or motherboard
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-197.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 0
         serial: B63A08C3
         slot: P2_DIMME1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm1_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm1_Manufacturer
         physical id: 1
         serial: Dimm1_SerNum
         slot: P2_DIMME2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 2
         serial: EA309638
         slot: P2_DIMMF1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm4_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm4_Manufacturer
         physical id: 3
         serial: Dimm4_SerNum
         slot: P2_DIMMF2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:4
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 4
         serial: E7305938
         slot: P2_DIMMG1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:5
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm7_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm7_Manufacturer
         physical id: 5
         serial: Dimm7_SerNum
         slot: P2_DIMMG2
         width: 64 bits
    *-bank:6
         description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
         product: 9965516-048.A
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 6
         serial: E7305B38
         slot: P2_DIMMH1
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:7
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm10_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm10_Manufacturer
         physical id: 7
         serial: Dimm10_SerNum
         slot: P2_DIMMH2
         width: 64 bits
 *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
      physical id: 7
 *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
      physical id: 9
```

As you can notice, there is no memory module on the bank #5 which. So my question is : do you agree this message is about memory failure? And if so, how can I find which module as to be replaced?

Answer (score 12):

These errors are coming from the EDAC - Error Detection And Correction.

`edac_mc` class of the device.

The events that you are receiving are CE events (Correctible Errors). These are indications that a DIMM is beginning to fail.

EDAC has not reported any specific information about which memory row or channel it refers to so it's difficult to tell which one to replace until that one fail.

but have a look at `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*` and this might tell you a little bit more about which row / DIMM that might be the faulty one.

For example

```
ls -s /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0
total 0
0 ce_count 0 csrow1 0 csrow4 0 csrow7 0 reset_counters 0 size_mb
0 ce_noinfo_count 0 csrow2 0 csrow5 0 device 0 sdram_scrub_rate 0 ue_count
0 csrow0 0 csrow3 0 csrow6 0 mc_name 0 seconds_since_reset 0 ue_noinfo_count
```

look at the `ce_count` field.

On a side note:

The system can still continue to operate, but with less safety. Preventive maintenance and proactive part replacement of memory DIMMs exhibiting CEs can reduce the likelihood of the dreaded UE (uncorrectible error) events and system 'panics'.

More info on EDAC here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/edac.txt

Comment: or reboot, and at the GRUB boot screen, select memtest and that might give you a bit more information.

Comment: No more MCE message this morning there (have no physical access to the server), waiting for it to check edac, good idea!

Comment: @kamger, memtest doesn't help with ECC memory.

Answer (score 3):

Some vendors say that several correctable errors during a certain period of time is of no harm.

For example, Oracle says replace a DIMM when one of the following events takes place:

- **More than 24 Correctable Errors (CEs)
  originate in 24 hours from a single DIMM** and no other DIMM is showing
  further CEs.
- The DIMM fails memory testing under BIOS due to Uncorrectable Memory
  Errors (UCEs).
- UCEs occur and investigation shows that the errors
  originated from memory.

Notice 24 errors in 24 hours.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19150-01/820-4213-11/dimms.html

Also,

> If more than one DIMM has experienced multiple CEs, other possible
>   causes of CEs must be ruled out by a qualified Sun Support specialist
>   before replacing any DIMMs.

On the last point, HP says something similar that it might be just the server firmware that misdetect memory errors. They say in many cases firmware upgrade fixes false positive alerts. This might be especially true if you started receiving MCEs from different DIMMs.

Answer (score 1):

It can help to install mcelog and run it as a daemon, it can help provide better reports. They are still cryptic but there is slightly more information to go with to find the culrpit DIMM.

mcelog can also handle real-time issues by disabling pages with excessive memory errors and thus giving you more chance to keep the machine running longer until you can recover it.

Comment: Thanks, it is what i have done but no more errors since first post. We decided to replace all of the DIMM.

Comment: Sometimes the errors are fleeting transients and sometimes they are simply tied to very specific locations that are rarely touched. If the errors didn't repeat I personally wouldn't have replaced the dimms and just kept monitoring, but replacing is valid as well.